# Function overloading error in my "date class"

Tags: c++

Afternoon folks! I am having issues with overloaded functions in a date class that I am working on. I got assigned this project.

These are my headers:

```
    //  Operators
        Date& operator++();                 // Pre-increment to next date       Done
        Date operator++(int);               // Post-increment to next date      Done
        Date& operator--();                 // Pre-decrement to prev date       Done
        Date operator--(int);               // Post-decrement to prev date      Done
```

This is my code:

```
/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
*   Function:   operator++(Date)                                            *
*                                                                           *
*   Purpose:    To pre-increment the specified date                         *
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/

Date Date::operator++()
{
    *this = *this + 1;
    return *this;
}

/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
*   Function:   operator++(Date, int)                                       *
*                                                                           *
*   Purpose:    To post-increment the specified date                        *
*                                                                           *
*   Note:       The "dummy" parameter of int is C++'s way of indicating     *
*               that this is the POST-increment operator. In usage, no      *
*               integer is provided.                                        *
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/

Date Date::operator++(int)
{
    Date original = *this;
    *this = *this + 1;
    return original;
}

/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
*   Function:   operator--(Date)                                            *
*                                                                           *
*   Purpose:    To pre-decrement the specified date                         *   
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/
Date Date::operator--()
{
    Date original = *this;
    *this = *this - 1;
    return original;
}

/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
*   Function:   operator--(Date, int)                                       *
*                                                                           *
*   Purpose:    To post-decrement the specified date                        *
*                                                                           *
*   Note:       The "dummy" parameter of int is C++'s way of indicating     *
*               that this is the POST-decrement operator. In usage, no      *
*               integer is provided.                                        *
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/

Date Date::operator--(int)
{
    *this = *this - 1;
    return *this;
}
```

This is the error message that Visual studio gives me:

```
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.cpp(593): error C2556: 'Date Date::operator ++(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'Date &Date::operator ++(void)'
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.h(65): note: see declaration of 'Date::operator ++'
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.cpp(593): error C2040: 'Date::operator ++': 'Date (void)' differs in levels of indirection from 'Date &(void)'
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.cpp(625): error C2556: 'Date Date::operator --(void)': overloaded function differs only by return type from 'Date &Date::operator --(void)'
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.h(67): note: see declaration of 'Date::operator --'
1>\coms261\project 4\project 4 - date class\date.cpp(625): error C2040: 'Date::operator --': 'Date (void)' differs in levels of indirection from 'Date &(void)'
```

I would sincerely appreciate any help, but I would like to actually understand why this is happening, so I code better in the future - rather than just a fix for the code. You guys at stack overflow are awesome. Once I learn to code, ill repay the favor of answering all the new guys stupid questions in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Typo? You declared the operator like this: `Date& operator++();`, but defined it like this: `Date Date::operator++()`. See the difference in the return value? This is exactly what the error is telling you.

Comment: Your pre-increment/decrement definitions are returning objects, not reference as you declared them to do.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I corrected this in my code. The project that I'm working on is a little bit weird though. My professor gave us the completed header file, as well as the prototypes of all the classes. The class is responsible for adding most of the actual functions - that is the challenge. Do you think my professor made a mistake in the function by not passing it by reference?

Comment: If your professor gave you the header file which contains the declarations (prototypes) and gave you the source file stubs for you to fill in, I would ask your professor about it. If only the header file was given, it's up to you to properly define those functions in the way they were declared.

Comment: @oXeru If the professor gave you a  header file, leaving you to implement those, you made a mistake in writing the return value, when defining them.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells explicitly  what's wrong here:

> overloaded function differs only by return type

Indeed, you declare in your .h

```
Date& operator++();
```

But in your .cpp:

```
Date Date::operator++()
```

See the difference? You're missing the reference for your return type. You should write the function this way:

```
Date& Date::operator++() {
   ...
```

You missed the reference in the 3rd operator, in your .cpp you wrote:

```
Date Date::operator--()
```

You should return a Date&

The second and fourth operators are OK.

Hope it helps